# Calculate the size of response header saved in a variable in JMeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell

I have extracted the complete response header and stored into a variable and below is the response header,

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 2951
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 17 Apr 2018 06:34:03 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=3175000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Vcap-Request-Id: de1csd11-2721-de3a-548e-573sdt3fae22
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Connection: close
```

Now i want to calculate the size of the above parsed data using Beanshell or Groovy or Javascript.

I used the function "variable.length()" but it did not help me as the parsed data have new line feed.

Can anyone please help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Hari

Comment: What about the `Content-Length: 2951` header/value?

Comment: it is as part of response header.

Answer (score 1):

For [Groovy/Beanshell](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#replaceAll(java.lang.CharSequence,%20groovy.lang.Closure)):

```
variable.replaceAll("\\n","").size()
```

For [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp):

```
variable.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '').length
```

Be aware that when it comes to high loads Groovy performance will be much better.

References:

- [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: I tried teh Beanshell one but it did not work out for me.